# XPath - replace element's name

Tags: xpath, replace

Sample html:

```
<div>
<button class="show-more-button" data-url="https://www.example.com/">
View More
</button>
</div>
```

I need a scraping project to interpret the BUTTON element as A and data-url as href:

```
<div>
<A class="show-more-button" href="https://www.example.com/">
View More
</button>
</div>
```

Here is my attempt so far. Tried with bothe replace and tranlate:

```
//DIV/BUTTON[translate(DIV, "BUTTON", "A")][translate(DIV, "data-url", "href")][contains(@class, "show-more-button")]
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Are you attempting to transform the `button` into an `a` element and transform the `@data-url` into an `@href` attribute, so that something else will recognize it as a regular anchor and follow the links? XPath is good for addressing items in markup, but if you want to transform the source into something different, would need more - such as XSLT, XQuery, or other language that would leverage XPath.

Comment: Right, need to transform the button into an a element and transform the data-url into an href attribute, so that something else will recognize it as a regular anchor and follow the links.

Comment: A single XPath can *select* either `A` elements with `href` attributes or `button` elements with `data-url` attributes, but to actually *transform* one to the other, you'd have to use a language hosting XPath (XSLT, Python, Java, etc) as Mads mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying an XSLT like this, you can transform the HTML and convert the `button` into `a` and `@data-url` into `@href`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="button">
        <a>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@data-url">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you only want to convert the `@data-url` of `button` elements, then adjust the generic match expression `@data-url` to `button/@data-url`.